# Hash Key REQUIRED

Tags: keytool

In some step of integrating app with the facebook Need to provide the Hash key. for that facebook developer gives this code to run in CMD

```
-keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore %HOMEPATH%\.android\debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

but when I do

I got **response** as

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "c:\Users\Sagar.Shah\.android\debug.keystore"
```

**Enter keystore password**:  android <-- I entered here invisibly

```
☺☺♂♣ 071♂0      ♠♥U♦♠‼☻US1►0♫♠♥U♦
430125104420Z071♂0      ♠♥U♦♠‼☻US1►0♫♠♥U♦
☺☺☺♣ ♥é☺☼ 0é☺0é☺"0
☻é☺☺ ¼╔WΩç~C╠╤√é:h♦⌂╘╬▒K▼n♂♣♫╣æΩïÅ▼rε«»wy&♠┘♀\#◄U¢║Ywσ+╗▀≥╞╤tΦ«U╓╥╗╠♂♫Q5╧£:fkf H
3╬Θ═/╝╪Tô→♀☻ì`'↔╤≈;ƒ²9≤░)∙%⌐ü╖C(t9»╢¶▲╣ëôpw*±╙æò▐²~═1╝πjKz╙╩┼ì☼L.öOó
╖yá≤«╗╗÷<å~ö₧ìR∞å█ ▐ Y⌠▄K┐]Aó∞⌐╡ö¿µ¬┬≡ì₧⌠Öµ:╓üx&‼böûƒÅ>╢)ΩÇ▌ë|▬←♥à┌ÿ─w¿)⌡╞♀¶±▄Oα
☺☺♂♣ ♥é☺☺ 8914IíL╚sFGFxg∞╪⌐▄í¡3ô↓Ü▼╬\╝y+!ú;¶r>°cÇªEñ≥Xés=╣╪ΩF¼}φµ-÷EWGHS>Å}E┤╜Y♠
1↕)`=l9▓)Üc♣¶▐╠vM╙-å♥vç░♫<å₧î{☺Ñ‼♫∩↓♥ ‼ìÑ╒èO☺♫ª¿¬╜o/┬º½ÿ←£╚±☺│+-à`ò▓t╔5┬ >ΣÉ3┐╥☺
¡╜Üß    ╫■≈τL½╧ë╤▲♠╚▲╝+ⁿ→♂╡O3Å└‼v°∙K↑╢p8W¡l╧╨σpë+╖╖a╜☼Θ├J.î≡╤&_;╟°≤LÆƒ*┘▓∩╠  ╚_∩
ⁿH÷§ò&)α δ↨╔►/a╬µ↨uÇ←7£╠v
```

I am stuck here.

Any help ???

Comment: Well, you forgot half the command, the `| openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64` part

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson - Actually I had written it but then Screen response as openssl is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: I just find that all Contents of openssl folder must be kept into Java\Jdk folder ..Then I run above command with appending | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 It gets run and I got my hash key..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to set full path of openssl as below:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin>keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey
 -keystore "C:\Users\Sagar.Shah\.android\debug.keystore" | "C:\Users\Sagar.Shah\
openssl\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Users\Sagar.Shah\openssl\bin\openssl
.exe" base64
```